# Spring OAUTH2 fetch userdetails on oauth client

Tags: single-sign-on, spring-security-oauth2

i'm fairly new to spring oauth2. I was wondering if it was possible to attached custom userdetails on the oauth client side.

something like this

```
    @EnableOAuth2Sso
    @Configuration
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
        private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;



        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        }

    }
```

this does not work as the configuration is somehow ignored.

this client authenticated in a spring oauth2 authentication server successfully, but i want to load the other user details after obtaining authorization.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Custom implementation of `UserDetailsService` is used to load user by username during authentication and that goes under `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`. We override its configure(..) method, the one that takes `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer` as parameter and set it there.

Similarly, we can write custom implementation of `ClientDetailsService`. During authentication this is used to load client by client id. This custom implementation is also registered the same way as `UserDetailsService`.

```
@Override
public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    endpoints.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore);
    endpoints.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
    endpoints.accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter);
}
```